# Prove there exists $c$ on $(a,b)$ such that $cf(c) = ab$ for all continuous $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, fixed-point-theorems

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ab > 0$ and consider $f : [a,b] \to [a,b]$ a continuous function.  Prove there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $cf(c) = ab$ (from [Berkely Math 104 Final](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F03_Final_Exam-D.Geba_.pdf)).

As stated in the exam, I don't believe this is correct, with $a = 1, b = 2, f(x) = 3 - x$ a counterexample.  **Am I correct?**

However, if we revise the question to ask for a $c \in [a,b]$, it is correct.  My proof is below.

Let $g(x) = ab/x$ and let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ on $[a,b]$.  We seek to prove that $h(x)$ has a zero on $[a,b]$.  $f, g,$ and $h$ are continuous.  $g(a) = b$, so $f(a) \leq g(a)$, and similarly $f(b) \geq g(b)$.  Since $h(a) \leq 0$ and $h(b) \geq 0$, by Bolzano's theorem, $h$ has a zero on $[a,b]$.  QED.

1. Is my proof correct?
2. Is there a better approach?
3. Given my approach, can the writing be improved?

Comment: Take $f(x)=a$, then $f$ is continuous, $cf(c)=ab$ only for $c=b$, so the statement is false. Your counterexample is also correct, as $3c-c^2=2$ has no solution in $(1,2)$

Comment: Maybe the hand copy you show is erroneous: it is easy to mis-transcript (...) instead of [...]...

Comment: The proof is also correct. Can you see where you used the hypothesis $ab>0$?

Comment: @Alessandro I wanted a counterexample where the image of $f$ is $[a,b]$, as, if this solved it, I would assume that was the intent of "$\to [a,b]$" in the question.  If $ab \leq 0$, $g$ isn't defined at zero and hence isn't continuous.  Should I have called that out? Is there another place I used it (without realizing)?

Comment: For me $\rightarrow[a,b]$ simply means that $f$ takes values in $[a,b]$, and need not be onto. I am not aware of other conventions. The reason for $ab>0$ is correct as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your counterexample is correct. You can generalize it to arbitrary intervals with
$$
 f(x) = a+b-x \, ,
$$
then the only solutions to $cf(c) = ab$ are $c=a$ and $c=b$.

Your proof is also correct. You can shorten it slightly by defining
$$
 h(x) = f(x) - \frac{ab}{x}
$$
directly, without the intermediate auxiliary function $g$. Then $h(a) = f(a) - b \le 0$ and $h(b) = f(b) - a \ge 0$, which implies that $h$ has a zero in $[a, b]$.